# tSQL NOT IN, logic not acting as expected

Tags: azure, t-sql

my first post here, learned a lot from this place through the last couple of years, thanks! Just graduated college as an Electronic Engineer mainly focusing on C, C++, VHDL etc. Got employed in a IoT company mainly using JS, C#, tSQL and Azure so my knowledge here is limited, please bear with me.

**Problem:**
I'm trying to sort out two specific device ID's in a Azure Query (transact SQL), and ensure that "NULL" does not get put into this specific table from these two specific ID's.

I've tried this code snippet below, which seems to be correct?
Even tho it seems correct to me, it does not behave as I expected, so must be wrong?

**Code:**

```
SELECT
    messagedata.device_name as device_name,
    messagedata.parsed.externaltemperature as external_temp,
    messagedata.parsed.humidity as humidity,
    messagedata.parsed.Moisture as moisture,
    messagedata.parsed.ExtTemp1 as extTemp1,
    messagedata.parsed.door_open as door_open,
    messagedata.parsed.CO2 as CO2,
    messagedata.parsed.di_1 as di_1, 
    messagedata.parsed.open_times as open_count,
    messagedata.parsed.open_duration as open_duration,
    messagedata.iothub.connectiondeviceid as gateway,
    messagedata.source_data.DevEUI as eui,   
    messagedata.device_type_id as device_type_id,
    TRY_CAST(messagedata.source_time AS datetime) AS enqueuedtime

INTO
    messagecurrent
FROM
    messagedata
    TIMESTAMP BY
        messagedata.source_time
WHERE 
messagedata.device_type_id NOT IN (1135, 1163) OR
(messagedata.device_type_id IN (1135, 1163) AND messagedata.parsed.di_1 IS NOT NULL)
```

**Objective:** Let every ID except 1135 and 1163 though, except when 1135 or 1163 is NOT NULL.

**Result:** ID 1135 OR ID 1163 passes, even if they are NULL. No other ID's passes this query.
In order to narrow down the problem, i removed the last OR clause in the original code snippet, resulting in:

```
WHERE 
messagedata.device_type_id NOT IN (1135, 1163)
```

The problem persists with this syntax. When I tried the following code snippet with just one ID, it works as expected:

```
WHERE
messagedata.device_type_id != 1163 OR (messagedata.device_type_id = 1163 AND messagedata.parsed.di_1 IS NOT NULL)
```

I tried looking through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) tSQL documentation with no luck.

Example data:
[messagecurrent data][1]

**DDL and DML statements** (if i understood this correct?)
Would really appreciate any feedback or suggestions.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.SensorCurrentData (
    id PK INT NOT NULL,
    enqueuedtime datetime NULL, 
    device_name varchar(50) NULL, 
    gateway varchar(50) NULL
    external_temp float NULL, 
    extTemp1 float NULL, 
    humidity float NULL, 
    moisture float NULL, 
    eui varchar(50) NULL, 
    alias varchar(50) NULL, 
    device_type_id int NULL, 
    open_duration int NULL, 
    battery_level int NULL, 
    door__open bit NULL, 
    open_count int NULL, 
    last_opened timestamp, NULL
    CO2 int NULL, 
    di_1 bit NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (id)
    VALUES (1163); 
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (enqueuedtime)
    VALUES (2021-09-15 08:47:19.583); 
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (device_name)
    VALUES ('Test');
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (gateway)
    VALUES ('321c32d7-c9ca-4b07-80df-1f2eb023471b');
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (external_temp)
    VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (extTemp1)
    VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (humidity)
    VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (moisture)
    VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (eui)
    VALUES (e084489a2b100000);
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (alias)
    VALUES ('Test-01');
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (device_type_id)
    VALUES (1163);
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (open_duration)
    VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (battery_level)
    VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (door__open)
    VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (open_count)
    VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (last_opened)
    VALUES (timestamp);
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (CO2)
    VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO dbo.SensorCurrentData (di_1)
    VALUES (1);
```

Comment: device_type_id  has nulls ?

Comment: No, the device_type_id is never null, but di_1 can some times be NULL, and i want to avoid putting this NULL into this specific table.

Comment: Thanks for the example code, could you also post some sample data for a Minimal, Reproducible Example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You don't show the `FROM` clause or any `JOIN`s and those could be causing some filtering behavior, please edit your question to provide more detail

Comment: I've added the FROM clause, no JOINs are used.

Comment: Images of data doesn't help us help you. Post it as DDL and DML statements. Don't forget to post your expected results for said data too.

Comment: Could you link an example of DDL/DML statements? Not familiar with this.

Comment: The Documentation has plenty: [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) - Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) & [INSERT (Transact-SQL) - Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#InsertExamples)

Comment: I added what i understood as DDL/DML statements, please correct me if wrong.